# How https://router.vuejs.org/ achieve native search with smooth scroll scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please use Chrome to visit the site https://router.vuejs.org/

And hit `command-f` to search `Getting Started`

Normally, the Chrome browser will directly jump to the searched text.

However, instead of directly jumping to the searched text, this site can smooth scroll to the search text.

How is this possible?

How can I achieve the same effect?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce

Comment: @Konowy did you use the latest Chrome?

Comment: I wrote the answer. I just have 1920 x 1080 screen

Comment: Oh, thank you! Sorry for the example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided unlucky example because this page is so small that there is nothing to scroll, but I could check it in som subpage.
The answer is this css:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

It doesn't change behaviour for searching, but overall scroll behaviour. You can check this by clicking this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation
Very useful for page anchors.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that site uses CSS to accomplish that:

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```